# How do I close all open network files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to convert my old BAT script to PowerShell version, 
but after one hour googling I have no idea how to do it.

I'm looking for a structure very similar to the old one, find open net files, 
get its PID and close it.

BAT:

```bat
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %a in ('net files ^| findstr C:\Apps\') do net files %a /close
```

PowerShell?

Comment: i don't think this is too narrow in scope, or unlikely to help others.  Closing network files is common.  I just needed the same exact thing.  This question is not asking for someone to convert a old batch file, but rather showing how it used to be done.

Comment: I agree, this questions shouldn't be closed. It's exactly what I need

Comment: Better suited for http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Net file is still your best bet. Try something like this:

```
$results = net file | Select-String -SimpleMatch "C:\Apps\"
foreach ($result in $results) {
    #Get id
    $id = $result.Line.Split(" ")[0]

    #Close file
    net file $id /close

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way. I like that it relies more on pipelining, which is the idiom of PowerShell:

```
net files | 
    where   { $_.Contains( "D:\" ) } |
    foreach { $_.Split( ' ' )[0] }   |
    foreach { net file $_ /close }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to view open files:

```
$adsi = [adsi]"WinNT://./LanmanServer"

$resources = $adsi.psbase.Invoke("resources") | Foreach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ID = $_.gettype().invokeMember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
        Path = $_.gettype().invokeMember("Path","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
        OpenedBy = $_.gettype().invokeMember("User","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
        LockCount = $_.gettype().invokeMember("LockCount","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
    }
}

$resources
```

Then filter the ones you want to close:

```
$resources | Where-Object { $_.Path -like 'c:\apps\*'} | 
Foreach-Object { net files $_.ID /close }
```

Comment: I like that you're going for an object-rich approach, instead of text munging, but in this case it's unwieldy.

Comment: Yup, you could wrap it in a function and hide the complexity. By the way, it could have been more complete, the collection used to have  Remove method to it used to have  Remove method but it seems to be missing. Another advantage of this is the option to run against remote machines, currently only to get the files.

Comment: It also gives you the full paths, whereas net file truncates paths.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#capture command output
$openfiles=net files
#parse all lines and watch for c:\apps\
$openfiles| foreach {
 if($_ -like '*c:\apps\*'){
    #if line contains c:\apps\ split it with space, the first element will be file id
    net files $_.split(' ')[0] /close
 }
}
```

Comment: Get-SmbOpenFile | Where-Object { $_.Path -like "c:\yourFolderName\*" } | Close-SmbOpenFile -Force

This command really worked for me

Comment: And remember to right-click and run the powershell window as administrator.