# No return value of the PS command "net file" while accessing the powershell remotely with .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell, remote-access

I've built a `Sub` to interact with PowerShells on other servers within my domain. I never needed any return values of the PS console so far. As I want to control the Computer Management on my FileShare I need the list of all open file-sessions (`net file`) as you need the session ID to close it with `net file "ID" /close`.

This is the modified Sub:

```
Public Sub remoteMSPowershell(ByVal Script As String)

    Dim shellUri As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell"
    Dim newCred As PSCredential = DirectCast(Nothing, PSCredential)
    Dim connectionInfo As WSManConnectionInfo = New WSManConnectionInfo(False, "SVR2012r2-file", 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, newCred)

    Using Runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)

        Runspace.Open()
        Dim pipeline As Pipeline = Runspace.CreatePipeline(Script)
        Dim results = pipeline.Invoke()

        For Each outputItem As PSObject In results
            Console.WriteLine(outputItem.Members("Path").Value)
            Console.WriteLine(outputItem.Members("Id").Value)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Using

End Sub
```

While `outputItem.BaseObject.ToString()` gives you 1:1 the same output as you see on the PS console, I only need the Attributes "Path" and "Id".

If I run this Sub on commands like `Get-Command`, `Get-Service` and so on it'll form a column with the values of the specified attribute. However if I run it on `net file` the script fails with a `NullReferenceException`. The only thing that I can imagine is that .NET is only capable of filtering to members (attributes) of Cmdlets, but I didn't find any reference on that.

EDIT (24.05.16): It doesn't work for all the [NET.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html) - commands.. Is there another way to read the return values out or even another method to get the return values using PS or .NET?

EDIT (26.05.16): I've been working on two work-arounds.. Both seem to be a dead end though:

- Unify the results from `outputItem.BaseObject.ToString()` and form Arrays of the "Id" and "Path" column. This won't work as the only indicator to split the rows into attributes are (blancs). You can imagine what happens if the File-Path contains a blanc..
- A more clean work-around would be to query the desired attributes already in PowerShell like the answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672479/how-do-i-close-all-open-network-files-in-powershell). However none of the given answers works for me as you can't query `NET` commands. See example:

[image: No queries allowed]

Comment: I don't know why you don't launch with Process class and pass input and output using StandardInput and StandardOutput.  Console.WriteLine writes to StandardOutput.

Comment: @jdweng I've read somewhere that the process class can only be used for the local powershell. However I tried it with the same result. Also if I readout the values into a string first - no difference